# WPF Path / "up" arrow gets 2px chopped off

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, drawing

I'm working on a WPF user control that essentially is a pimped-up Expander control. In order to get the control to look identical whether it's running on *Windows Classic* or *Aero* theme, I've managed to set up a control template that pretty much mimicks the *Aero* up/down arrows.

The "down" arrow looks exactly as it should. But the "up" arrow gets [what seems to be] 2 pixels chopped off and that makes it look a bit rounded, which I'd like to fix:

[image: Arrows comparison]

Here's the complete `<Path>` markup:

```
<Path x:Name="arrow" 
        Margin="0,5,0,0" 
        Stroke="SteelBlue" 
        Data="M 0 5 L 5 0 L 10 5" 
        StrokeThickness="2" 
        Height="10" Width="10" />
```

I'd like to know what to change in order to get back my two pixels - I tried tweaking margin and height but no luck. I'm sure it's just a tiny little adjustment that's missing, just can't figure out what and where exactly. Anyone?

Also I need to figure out why the top border looks crooked... but that's beyond the scope of this question!

**EDIT** - Here's enough markup to reproduce the style; apply style `NormalExpander` to an `Expander` control and you should see what I'm seeing...

```
    <Style x:Key="ExpanderDownHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                    <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Height="25">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="SteelBlue" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
                            <Path x:Name="arrow" Margin="0,5,0,0" Stroke="SteelBlue" Data="M 0 5 L 5 0 L 10 5" StrokeThickness="2" Height="10" Width="10" />
                            <!-- down arrow: M 0 0 L 5 5 L 10 0 -->
                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF3C7FB1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="#222"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="circle" Value="#FF526C7B"/>
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="circle" Value="1.5"/>
                            <Setter Property="Stroke" TargetName="arrow" Value="DarkBlue"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Data" TargetName="arrow" Value="M 0 5 L 5 0 L 10 5" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="NormalExpander" TargetType="Expander">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <DockPanel>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="HeaderSite" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" ContentTemplateSelector="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplateSelector}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontWeight="{TemplateBinding FontWeight}" FontStyle="{TemplateBinding FontStyle}" FontStretch="{TemplateBinding FontStretch}" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontFamily="{TemplateBinding FontFamily}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" MinWidth="0" MinHeight="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{StaticResource ExpanderDownHeaderStyle}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ExpandSite" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Focusable="false" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ExpandDirection" Value="Up">
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="ExpandSite" Value="Top"/>
                            <Setter Property="DockPanel.Dock" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="Bottom"/>
                            <Setter Property="Style" TargetName="HeaderSite" Value="{StaticResource ExpanderUpHeaderStyle}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Found a solution - using paths `up: M 1 4 L 5 0 L 9 4 | down: M 1 0 L 5 4 L 9 0` makes a tighter arrow, that doesn't get clipped. I still don't know what caused the clipping, but I'll use the smaller arrow at leave happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the `Margin`, `Height` and `Width` and align the arrow data centrally it will not clip the `Path` data. You will need to shift the arrow slightly to the right to get it in the centre of the `Ellipse`.

```
<Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="False" Height="25">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Ellipse x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="19" Stroke="SteelBlue" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="19"/>
    <Path x:Name="arrow" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stroke="SteelBlue" Data="M 0.5 5 L 5.5 0 L 10.5 5" StrokeThickness="2" />
    <!-- down arrow: M 0.5 0 L 5.5 5 L 10.5 0 -->
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: +1 Yup, that was it! Makes total sense to center-align the arrow, I knew it had to be a tiny little thing!

Comment: And yet another couple of hours saved! +1